# If $V \hookrightarrow H$ are Hilbert spaces and $f \in H'$ then $f \in V'$?

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $H=(H, (\cdot, \cdot)_H)$ and $V=(V, (\cdot, \cdot)_V)$ be Hilbert spaces such that $V \hookrightarrow H$ that is $V$ is  [continuously embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_embedding#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20one%20normed%20vector%20space%20is%20said,the%20Sobolev%20embedding%20theorems%20are%20continuous%20embedding%20theorems.) in $H$. By Riesz representation theorem we can identify $H=H'$. Thus we have
$$V \hookrightarrow H=H' \hookrightarrow  V'.$$

Since $H' \hookrightarrow  V'$ then, in particular, $H' \subset V'$.

**Question.** If $f \in H'$ then we can to say that $f \in V'$?

I think so, in virtue of $H' \subset V'$. But more formally, due to $f \in H'$ then $f$ is linear. Now, I want to prove that $f$ is bounded (in $V'$). So I can to write, for every $v \in V$,
$$\langle f , v \rangle _{V',V}= \langle f , v \rangle _{H',H} \leq \|f\|_{H'}\cdot \|v\|_{H} \leq \|f\|_{H'}\cdot c\cdot \|v\|_{V}?$$
Here, $c>0$ is the constant of the embedding $V \hookrightarrow H$.

Comment: Tip: use \| \| for norms, its more beautiful then || ||. Regarding your question, seems correct to me, but I lack confidence in functional analysis so lets wait for someone with more expertise

Comment: @DaniloGregorinAfonso Thanks for your tip. I fixed.

Comment: What you write is correct. But sometimes it is better to be more careful about what kind of objects you are looking at - for example if $f\in H'$ it is strictly speaking not true that $f\in V'$, but rather that $f$ _induces_ an element of $V'$ via the map $v\mapsto f (i(v))$ for $i:V\to H$ the embedding. This map $f\circ i : V\to\Bbb C$ is continuous and linear as a composition of continuous linear maps so there is no need to do a calculation.

Comment: Hi! Is $V$ a subspace of $H$? If not, then if I were you, I would be careful when writing $ \langle f, v \rangle_{V',V}$

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen Yes, $V$ is subspace of $H$, Since $V \hookrightarrow H$.

Comment: @s.harp Please, put your comment as a answer. So I can put my question as answered.

Comment: The natural map from $H'$ to $V'$, precisely described by @s.harp, may not be injective, so there is no meaningful sense to interpret the inclusion $H'\subseteq V'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof you have written works. Denoting the inclusion by $i:V\to H$ you have for $f\in H$ and $v\in V$ that:

$$|f(i(v))| ≤\|f\|_{H'} \cdot \|i(v)\|_H ≤ \|f\|_{H'}\cdot \|i\|_{L(V,H)}\cdot \|v\|_{V}$$

where you applied boundedness of $f$ and $i$ as linear maps to get that $v\mapsto f(i(v))$ is bounded as a linear map (with bound $\|f\|_{H'} \cdot \|i\|_{L(V,H)}$).

Depending on how precise you want to be it is not entirely correct to say that $f$ is an element of $V'$. Rather you should say that any $f\in H'$ induces an element of $V'$ by the prescription $f\mapsto f\circ i$.

Understanding the problem in that way also gives you a more immediate understanding why you get an element of $V'$, for $f\circ i:V\mapsto \Bbb K$ is continuous and linear as a composition of continuous linear maps.

Comment: So, since I can to identify (by Representation Riesz Theorem) $H=H'$, can I to say that $H' \hookrightarrow V'$?

Comment: You get a map $H'\to V'$. If you use Riesz this becomes a map $i^*:H\to V$, which is the _adjoint_ of the map $i: V\to H$. $i^*$ will be injective if $i(V)$ is dense in $H$.

Comment: I meant that if $V$  continuously embedded in $H$, then $ H '$ continuously embedded $ V' $?

Comment: No, you have a map $H'\to V'$. If the embedding of $V$ into $H$ has dense image then the map $H'\to V'$ is injective - only in this case can you say that you have a continuous embedding.